# PhpMyAdmin Error 2002

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, easyphp

I currently have a problem with PhpMyAdmin, I am using EasyPHP and everytime I try to access PhpMyAdmin, it gives me this error:

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)
```

I've tried reinstalling EasyPHP about 5 times, rebooting the machine multiple times, playing around the config files, nothing works. Does anyone have any advice before I format my HDD to solve this problem? I'm currently running Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have already resolved the issue (or not?) but as I see it is a common problem I will post how I came up with a solution. What I did, after playing around with the error for a whole day or so, I downloaded the new version of MySQL through the [wamp website](http://www.wampserver.com) (Download MySQL Addons at the bottom) After installing it, I clicked on the Wamp Tray Icon. Clicked on MySQL --> Version --> And chose the new version. It restarted by itself and it worked like a charm! Hope that will help some people :)

Answer (score 0):

I just spent 30 minutes trying to help a colleague debug an EasyPHP installation that would not allow him to view the PHPMyAdmin module.

He was using EasyPHP14.1vc11 Development Version stock installation on a Windows 7x86 PC. He was right clicking on the tray icon, going to 'Administration' and then clicking on the blue 'Open' button next to the PHPMyAdmin module on the main page.

The error message he was receiving was:

```
#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

After a lot of debugging and trial and error, we found that the issue was there was a mysql process that was still running on his computer (found by Ctrl+Alt+Delete -> Task Manager) even when EasyPHP was closed. The process must have died but not been killed off properly and it was blocking PHPMyAdmin from making another connection to the database. Stopping that process removed the error message and allowed the program to work as intended.